# Issue in iOS 10 while sending location info to my server whenever my application is in background

Tags: ios, nstimer, cllocationmanager

In my application, i have a requirement to send my location details to an exposed Webservice in every 2 mins. How i could do that ? When i implemented the above mentioned operation using NSTimer, timer is getting suspended in 3 mins whenever the application is in background. I'd tried with backgroundExpirationHandler, but the operation is not performing after a set of time interval. Any suggestions ?

Note - I have added "App registers for location updates" in info.plist as well.

Comment: You can't do it "every two minutes".  You can do it "each time you get a location update" and you can keep track of the last time you updated the server and only send an update if it has been more than two minutes since the last update.  If the device isn't moving or has bad location coverage then you may not get updates for some time.

Comment: Is there any possibility to do that operation in every 2 minutes using Timer or Perform Selector ?

Comment: No, timers don't run when your app is suspended

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to add permission for background location updates in Capabilities, then you should tweak following properties of your location manager:

```
self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
locationManager.distanceFilter // get location callback after device moves to this defined distance
locationManager.desiredAccuracy //according to your requirement
```

So whenever any of the above said tweaks happen , you get callback in your delegate method. Upon receiving that you can update your app server for your location.

Comment: CoreLocation delegates will fire on that time. But as the application is in suspended state, whether i am able to do an operation like calling a service to let server knows about the updated location within the delegates ?

Comment: Actually you can setup your application to launch by location callbacks even when your app is killed. But in that case 2 rule will not apply. You will get a callback when a signification location will be moved say 500 meters.